# How to get integer from superview in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to get a integer from a viewcontroller and pass to a subclass cell.m. Here is the code:

the superview controller h.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger cellnumberinrow;
```

the superview controller m.

```
self.cellnumberinrow = 5; (it may change later)


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"wordscollectioncell";

CVcell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

CVcell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger cellnumberinrow;
```

CVcell.m

```
self.cellnumberinrow= [(superview Controller *)[self superview] cellnumberinrow];
```

No error return but get crash on runtime. Why? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please add the crash logs

Comment: I am new and I don't know which part is needed. So I paste them all.

Comment: 2014-11-02 20:53:08.448 ChineseTemplate[732:16682] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5f0f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e289bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5f0e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
 3   QuartzCore                          0x000000010c41b4e6 _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 152

Comment: 16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e51b486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
 17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011035a9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
 18  UIKit                               0x000000010cb32420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
 19  ChineseTemplate                     0x000000010c27c233 main + 115
 20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010fe9c145 start + 1
 21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: please edit the question with the your logs

Comment: Sorry I am new to Xcode and I don't know how to decode the logs. Any help?

Comment: Now I know the "edit" means, I won't make the same mistake twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`self.cellnumberinrow = [(superview Controller *)[self superview] cellnumberinrow];` in CVcell.m

Please, consider use

`cell.cellnumberinrow = self.cellnumberinrow;` in the method `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I just tried. Got the same warning. Here is the thing. I use cellnumberinrow to resize the uicollectionview cell in layout, then I pass this number to CVcell.m to set up label size. My best guest is I don't get the order right but I don't know how to fix it. Still many thanks.

Comment: Here is the layout code:[self.flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth/self.cellnumberinrow, screenWidth/self.cellnumberinrow*1.2)];